# How can I limit certain topics to be used only by specific clients?

Tags: mqtt, emq

How do I configure emqx v3.2.1 that I used?

Comment: Please make sure you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the doc on how to ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

EMQX allows you to configure Access Control Lists to authorise access to topics.

See https://github.com/emqx/emqx/wiki/ACL-Design and https://docs.emqx.io/broker/v3/en/config.html#anonymous-authentication-and-acl-files

e.g. an acl.config file with:

```
{allow, {user, "testuser"}, subscribe, ["a/b/c", "d/e/f/#"]}.
{allow, {user, "admin"}, pubsub, ["a/b/c", "d/e/f/#"]}.
{deny, all}.
```

will allow the client `testuser` to subscribe to topics `a/b/c` and `d/e/f/#` only, while `admin` is allowed to publish and subscribe these topics.